# Storing a list of mixed types in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

In Cassandra, when specifying a table and fields, one has to give each field a type (`text`, `int`, `boolean`, etc.). The same applies for collections, you have to give lock a collection to specific type (`set<text>` and such).

I need to store a list of mixed types in Cassandra. The list may contain numbers, strings and booleans. So I would need something like `list<?>`.

Is this possible in Cassandra and if not, What workaround would you suggest for storing a list of mixed type items? I sketched a few, but none of them seem the right way to go...

Comment: After realizing the traffic for the question was low, I asked this on cassandra users mailing list and got some more replies there: http://www.mail-archive.com/user@cassandra.apache.org/msg37103.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested at http://www.mail-archive.com/user@cassandra.apache.org/msg37103.html I decided to encode the various values into binary and store them into `list<blob>`. This allows to still query the collection values (in Cassandra 2.1+), one just needs to encode the values in the query.

On python, simplest way is probably to pickle and hexify when storing data:

```
pickle.dumps('Hello world').encode('hex')
```

And to load it:

```
pickle.loads(item.decode('hex'))
```

Using `pickle` ties the implementation to python, but it automatically converts to correct type (int, string, boolean, etc.) when loading, so it's convenient.

Comment: +1 I was wondering about this one, and thought that maybe you'd be able to solve this in Cassandra 2.1, which is supposed to have user-defined types.  Good workaround, though.

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23 The user defined types does not help, actually. I could define a `list<myowntype>` but then, I would need to still specify separate fields for each type. So it would work yeah, but would not be any better than using separate lists for each type.

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra's CQL interface is strictly typed, so you will not be able to create a table with an untyped collection column.

I basically see two options:

- Create a list field, and convert everything to text (not too nice, I agree)
- Use the [thift API](http://programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.cassandra.thrift.ConsistencyLevel) and store everything as is.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I also considered converting everything to string (adding some sort of metadata prefix, e.g. "!int:<value>"), but it's indeed ugly and makes queries difficult. I'm new to Cassandra, but I see Thrift protocol somewhat deprecated and would like to avoit it (even the cqlsh in coming 2.1 release seems to use native protocol instead of Thrift).